# Nimbus L&F trying to change background color of JFormattedTextField with UIManager

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus, uimanager

### SSCCE

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

public class Test extends JFrame{

    private JFormattedTextField input, input2;
    private NumberFormatter formatter;


    public Test() {
        formatter = new NumberFormatter(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance());
        input = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        input2 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);


        input.setColumns(4);
        input2.setColumns(4);
        input.setValue(0.0);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(input);
        panel.add(input2);

        add(panel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    UIManager.put("nimbusBase", new ColorUIResource(0, 0, 0));
                    UIManager.put("FormattedTextField.background", Color.RED);
                    UIManager.put("control", new ColorUIResource(153, 76, 0));
                    UIManager.put("textForeground", new ColorUIResource(255, 153, 51));
                    break;
                } }
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

### Problem

Simply put I'm attempting to change the background color of an `Enabled` `JFormattedTextField` from the default white to my RGB color.  I used the table found [here](http://jasperpotts.com/blogfiles/nimbusdefaults/nimbus.html) (Link in this [blog](http://www.jasperpotts.com/blog/2008/08/nimbus-uimanager-uidefaults/)) to find the appropriate name.

I realize the blog is a little bit outdated (6 years) and `Nimbus` has been updated a ton since then, so this might be my issue.

How do I go about using `UIManager` to change the background color of a `JFormattedTextField`?

### Corrected Code

I updated the code above, it works as it should now.  The issue was using `ColorUIResource` instead of just `Color`.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html) link? `FormattedTextField.background`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I go about using UIManager to change the background color of a
>   JFormattedTextField?

You have to set this property `FormattedTextField.background` as found here [Nimbus Defaults](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html)

Something like this

```
 UIManager.put("FormattedTextField.background", Color.RED);
```

Comment: I'm stupid, I didn't include that in the SSCCE.  Updating my code again.  But short and sweet, doesn't work.

EDIT scratch that, UIResource isn't the way to set it apparently.

Comment: @Eric Actually if you read the link i provide, if you set `FormattedTextField[Enabled].backgroundPainter` or the property you want this a `Painter`